# Svn commit fails due to outdated file despite updating directory

Tags: xcode, svn

I get a strange error when I try to commit my file. The error I get is

```
svn: E160042: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160042: File or directory 'xyz.m' is out of date; try updating
svn: E160024: resource out of date; try updating
```

I updated the file using `svn up` in the command line as well as in XCode. When I update, I get a success message that says all files have been updated. However, when I try commit, I get the same issue again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there is no *branch* change ?

Comment: yes, i am on the same branch

Comment: please clean the branch and try...